# Pass data between Angular2 routes similar to modal dialog

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Is it possible to return data from one route to another in Angular2? Similar to using modals to search/select some data and then return it back.

I'm looking for something like this:

1. The app begins in /mainRoute
2. The users clicks a search button
3. Navigate to /search
4. Load the new route/component
5. The user selects  X data
6. I "close" the current route (i.e. return to /mainRoute)
7. /mainRoute component has now the X object

In Angular1 I did my own Routing service that implemented this with promises:

```
MyRouter.openView('/...../').then(function(returnData){ })
```

Is there something like this in Angular2? I also read about [ngrx/router](https://github.com/ngrx/router) but I found nothing similar to this.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to share data between multiple route components. A common pattern is to build a service that is shared/inject into any component where you want to share that data. Then you can call write or read the data via the service from each of the component to fetch the same data.

BTW promises work just fine in Angular2.

**a.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SharedService } from './shared.service.ts';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-component-a',
  templateUrl: 'a.component.html'
})
export class ComponentA implements OnInit {
  constructor (private sharedService: SharedService) {}

  ngOnInit () {
    this.sharedService.write('Hello from component A');
  }
}
```

**b.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SharedService } from './shared.service.ts';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-component-b',
  templateUrl: 'b.component.html'
})
export class ComponentA implements OnInit {
  constructor (private sharedService: SharedService) {}

  ngOnInit () {
    let message = this.sharedService.read();
    // message should now be the string `Hello from component A'
  }
}
```

**shared.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class SharedService {
  private message: string = null;

  constructor () {}

  read () {
    return this.message;
  }

  write (newMessage: string) {
    this.message = newMessage;
  }
}
```

[ngrx/**store**](https://github.com/ngrx/store) is another option too. The idea there is that you have a single application state where you store all your app data there. You can make calls to the store to fetch data, or you can call **reducers** which will update your app data. There's a LOT of things to cover just this topic alone, so I highly recommend reading up on this before trying this approach.

Sorry for the long writeup, but wanted to add one more thing about this. :)
In Angular2, there is a `resolve guard` you can use to pre-fetch data for any routes. It will still require some sort of service that you can get data from. But this is nice if you want your view to be ready for rendering by the time you get to it. [Here's more info about that](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#resolve-guard)